# Deserialize JSON data with double quote using JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, special-characters

Below JSON data i'm trying to deserialize using `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize` but, am getting below exception.

**Code:**

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
FCMCasepackVM casepack = jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<FCMCasepackVM>(selectedCasePack);
```

**JSON Data:**

```
 { P_ID:"1478952", P_NM:"BAHLSEN COOKIES WAFER ROLL MILK CHOCOLATE 3.5
 OZ", BYR_ID:191, BYR_NM:"BYR_NM", VDR_ID:48532, VDR_NM:"KEHE FOOD DIST
 INC", CPK_ID:"1478952-12", CPK_DSC:"BAHLSEN COOKIES WAFER ROLL MILK
 CHOCOLAT", VDR_IT_CD_ID:"6398", UPC_ID:7056921950.0,
 CPK_PRI_FLG:"True", CPK_SRC:"PEF", **FCM_RGLT_TYP_CT:"FSV"P"**,
 CPK_P_ORIG_DSC:"", RGLN_EXCL_FLG:"False", BRND_TYP:""  }
```

**Exception**

> Additional information: Cannot convert object of type 'System.String'
>   to type 'Meijer.MerchProduct.FCM.Models.ViewModels.FCMCasepackVM'

Even I tried serializing the data before deserialize however getting a different exception

**Code:**

```
var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
selectedCasePack = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(selectedCasePack);
FCMCasepackVM casepack = jsonSerialiser.Deserialize<FCMCasepackVM>(selectedCasePack);
```

**JSON Data after serialize**

```
 "{ P_ID:\"1478952\", P_NM:\"BAHLSEN COOKIES WAFER ROLL MILK CHOCOLATE
 3.5 OZ\", BYR_ID:191, BYR_NM:\"BYR_NM\", VDR_ID:48532, VDR_NM:\"KEHE FOOD DIST INC\", CPK_ID:\"1478952-12\", CPK_DSC:\"BAHLSEN COOKIES
 WAFER ROLL MILK CHOCOLAT\", VDR_IT_CD_ID:\"6398\",
 UPC_ID:7056921950.0, CPK_PRI_FLG:\"True\", CPK_SRC:\"PEF\",
 FCM_RGLT_TYP_CT:\"FSV\"P\", CPK_P_ORIG_DSC:\"\", RGLN_EXCL_FLG:\"False\", BRND_TYP:\"\"  }"
```

**Exception**

> Additional information: Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected.
>   (319): { P_ID:"1478952", P_NM:"BAHLSEN COOKIES WAFER ROLL MILK
>   CHOCOLATE 3.5 OZ", BYR_ID:191, BYR_NM:"BYR_NM", VDR_ID:48532,
>   VDR_NM:"KEHE FOOD DIST INC", CPK_ID:"1478952-12", CPK_DSC:"BAHLSEN
>   COOKIES WAFER ROLL MILK CHOCOLAT", VDR_IT_CD_ID:"6398",
>   UPC_ID:7056921950.0, CPK_PRI_FLG:"True", CPK_SRC:"PEF",
>   FCM_RGLT_TYP_CT:"FSV"P", CPK_P_ORIG_DSC:"", RGLN_EXCL_FLG:"False",
>   BRND_TYP:""  }

can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Karthik

Comment: looks like you have a malformed json string, the second exception tells you that. The FCM_RGLT_TYP_CT key seems problematic as there are 3 double quotes, one of which should be escaped or removed

Answer (score 0):

Where this json data is serialised? quotes should have escaped during serialisation.

This JSON data is invalid, if you have access to app serialising this json data you should change that to escape quotes in the string. (usually all library does that automatically during serialisation)

Update

Hi Karthik, see following code to serialise the objects in JSON format using newtonsoft's library.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var d = new DoTheWork();
        d.SerializeSample();
    }
}


public class Sample
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class DoTheWork
{

    public string SerializeSample()
    {
        List<Sample> sampleList = new List<Sample>();
        sampleList.Add(new Sample { Id = "1", Description = "Karthik" });
        sampleList.Add(new Sample { Id = "1", Description = "Sujit" });
        sampleList.Add(new Sample { Id = "1", Description = "John\"s" });

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(sw, sampleList);

        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(sb.ToString());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Above JSON data is not serialized using any serialization method instead it has been formed manually on VIEW side. Can you please help me how to form JSON data with quotes? For ex: DESC:8" round table

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are using is invalid and without knowing your container object of FCMCasepackVM and how you got the JSON it is hard to tell what went wrong where.  Here is a simple example using the built in System.Web.Script.Serialization technique with the JavaScriptSerializer.

```
public class POC
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Desc { get; set; }
}

static List<POC> GetPOCOs()
{
  return new List<POC>
  {
      new POC { Id = 1, Desc = "John"},
      new POC { Id = 2, Desc = "Jane" },
      new POC { Id = 3, Desc = "Joey" }
  };
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var pocos = GetPOCOs();

  var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  var sjson = serializer.Serialize(pocos);
  var djson = serializer.Deserialize<List<POC>>(sjson);

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When I serialize to JSON in text it should look like this:

```
[{"Id":1,"Desc":"John"},{"Id":2,"Desc":"Jane"},{"Id":3,"Desc":"Joey"}]
```

Or a single item may be:

```
{"Id":1,"Desc":"John"}
```

NOT:

```
{Id:1,Desc:"John"}
```

Generally a key pair system is all JSON is but it needs the key surrounded with quotes to be able to know what it is.  If you are ever in doubt, use an online JSON validator like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sorry!! its my bad not provided the complete details about my class. My question is, instead of serializing the object to JSON, how to form JSON string manully with quotes. I'm taking your JSON data for my example
this data is pretty neat & easy to deserialize to source object[{"Id":1,"Desc":"John"},{"Id":2,"Desc":"Jane"},{"Id":3,"Desc":"Joey"}]
how about below one?
[{"Id":1,"Desc":"Joh"n"},{"Id":2,"Desc":"Jane"},{"Id":3,"Desc":"Joey"}]

Comment: You should not be serializing anything for JSON, XML, or certainly binary manually.  Just use the built in's in .NET.  If you go down the path of doing things manually you may get many invalid elements and syntax.  If you are wanting to put a double quote in your string just do an esacpe on it \" then serialize that.